# C# WPF Update two user controls using dependency property located in another project

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I am trying to set a common dependency property to two different user controls in WPF.
I tried lots of solutions that I found but none of them worked. 
So for the moment what I got is the following:

I have a class containing the common property which currently (after trying almost everything) looks this way:

```
namespace CommonProperties {
public class CommonProp : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTrueProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("IsTrue", typeof(bool), typeof(CommonProp), new PropertyMetadata(false));
    private bool _isTrue;
    public bool IsTrue
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsTrueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsTrueProperty, value); NotifyPropertyChanged("IsTrue"); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string nomPropriete)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nomPropriete));
    }
}}
```

I also have two user controls which looks like that: 
 UC1:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ClassLibUC1.UC1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:CommonProperties;assembly=CommonProperties"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="text1"
             Width="254"
             Height="23"
             Margin="24,24,0,0"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Text="{Binding IsTrue}"
             TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <Button Width="75"
            Margin="70,68,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Click="Button_Click"
            Content="Button" />

</Grid>
```

UC1 ViewModel:

```
namespace ClassLibUC1 {
public class ViewModelUC1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    CommonProp prop = new CommonProp();

    public bool IsTrue
    {
        get { return prop.IsTrue; }
        set { prop.IsTrue = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsTrue"); }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Trigger the PropertyChanged event to update views.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nomPropriete"></param>
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string nomPropriete)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nomPropriete));
    }
}
```

UC1 Code:

```
  public partial class UC1 : UserControl
{
    ViewModelUC1 vm = new ViewModelUC1();
    public UC1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CommonProp prop = new CommonProp();

        if (vm.IsTrue)
        {
            vm.IsTrue = false;
        }
        else
        {
            vm.IsTrue = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The second user control is exactly the same. The problem is that when I click a button in the first or the second user control, it only updates the selected control and not both of them.. Any idea how can I implement a common property for both controls?

Comment: You can use static normal property (or field) to hold same value for all instances. Another option is storing the value outside. If there is an external model/viewmodel to hold `bool` value, then all instances of user controls can use it (in view or their viewmodel).

Answer (score 0):

With Dependency property we cannot achieve this because Dependency property belongs to one instance, means if you have two instance of user control, updating DependencyProperty value of one control will never update DependencyProperty of other Control as it is a different instance all together.

But still we can achieve that requirement of updating Same value for all usercontrols of same type like yours. For that we have to do some modification in xaml.cs file like below.

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for UC1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class UC1 : UserControl
{
    private static List<UC1> _allInstanceOfThisControl = new List<UC1>();
    ViewModelUC1 vm = new ViewModelUC1();
    public UC1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = vm;
        _allInstanceOfThisControl.Add(this);
        this.Unloaded += UC1_Unloaded;
    }

    private void UC1_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _allInstanceOfThisControl.Remove(this);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (vm.IsTrue)
        {
            vm.IsTrue = false;
        }
        else
        {
            vm.IsTrue = true;
        }

        var _allInstanceOfThisControlExceptthis = _allInstanceOfThisControl.Where(s => s != this).ToList();
        _allInstanceOfThisControlExceptthis.ForEach(s =>
        {
            (s.DataContext as ViewModelUC1).IsTrue = vm.IsTrue;
        });
    }
```

Hope this will help to achieve your requirement.